# Count lines in text

Tags: python-2.7, count

I am trying to count how many sentences are there in a set of files' abstracts. The first paragraph of code below is to open all folders and files. The second piece grabs the file IDs and abstracts to count sentence numbers. I want a list of results show me how many sentences (lineCount here) each file has.

```
# open multiple files.
import re, os
topdir = r'E:\Grad\LIS\LIS590 Text mining\Part123\Part1' 
matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(topdir):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(('.txt','.pdf')):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

capturedfiles = []
capturedabstracts = []
Abs=open('countsent.csv','w')
for filepath in matches:
    with open (filepath,'rt') as mytext:
        mytext=mytext.read()

    # code to capture file IDs.
    grabFile=re.findall(r'File\s+\:\s+(\w\d{7})',mytext)
    if len(grabFile) == 0:
        matchFile= "N/A"
    else:
        matchFile = grabFile[0]
    capturedfiles.append(matchFile)
    #print capturedfiles

    # code to capture abstracts
    newtext=re.sub(r'\n',' ',mytext)
    newtext=re.sub(r'\s+',' ',newtext)
    grabAbs=re.findall(r'Abstract\s+\:(\w.+)',newtext)
    if len(grabAbs) == 0:
        matchAbs= "N/A"
    else:
        matchAbs = grabAbs[0]
    capturedabstracts.append(matchAbs)

    lineCount = 0
    lines = matchAbs[0].split('. ')
    for line in lines:
        lineCount +=1
        Abs.write(matchFile + '|' + str(lineCount) + '\n')
Abs.close()
```

The output is not right. 

`a9000006|1
a9000031|1
a9000038|1
a9000040|1
a9000043|1`

I need to count the total number of sentences in every abstract. To do so I used lineCount, but the results are wrong. Not sure how to correct it. Here is an example of the results I want: a9000006|4 a9000031|11. 4 and 11 are the number of sentences in these abstracts Many thanks.

Comment: *"how to output sSentenceNumber + matchFile?"* what is the issue? There is no `SentenceNumber` in your code. What do you expect to happen (input/output)? What happens instead? Provide [*minimal* code example that shows your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have updated my code. The SentenceNumber is lineCount. But the output lineCount is not the right value, I want it be the total sentence number of every file.

Comment: 1. Remove unrelated code. Make it work for a single file first 2. your code already outputs lineCount + matchFile 3. Describe using plain English what do you expect your code to do and what happens instead. See my previous comment.

Comment: re2: Did you see the results? It is not what I want. re3: I have explained that I need to count the total number of sentences in every file. To do so I used `lineCount`, but the results are wrong. Not sure how to correct it. Here is an example of the results I want: `a9000006|4 a9000031|11`. 4 and 11 are the number of sentences in these abstracts.

Comment: don't put the relevant info in comments. Update your question instead. Your code hints that you do not use a usual definition for "line/sentence count" and the code is broken. Therefore you should use plain English to describe what you want

Comment: Updated. Please let me know if it is clear now.

Comment: *"how many sentences are there in a set of files' abstracts"*: how many file ids, abstracts are there in a single physical file (`filepath`)? How do these ids, abstracts are distinguished from a surrounding text inside the input files? How do you define a sentence e.g., how many sentences do you think here: *'Rabbit say to itself "Oh dear! Oh dear! I shall be too late!"'*. Remember, if your code is broken then you can't use it to define things, use words instead. And/or provide a representative input file as an example.

Comment: Have thousands of files nested under a few levels of folders. Here is the example of a file path: `E:\Grad\LIS\LIS590 Text mining\Part123\Part1\awards_1994\awd_1994_00`. Not sure which part of the code is broken. Works okay on my laptop.

Comment: I've asked about **single** file: its content, I don't care about its name on your local computer. If your code is not broken then what is your question?